# salt vs salt-call and notification

Tags: salt-stack

i played with salt and read the docs, but there are still 2 questions open.
what is the preferred way, push or pull (in unattended mode, periodically)?

- **push**: is it preferred to do **salt '*' state.highstate** periodically from salt-master to the minions, or
- **pull**: do a periodically **salt-call** on the minions

notifications?
is there a built-in notification function on state-errors? because, when it runs periodically i want an email if theres an error applying a state
or should i try to find a way with graylog or logwatch or something like that?

thx

Answer (score 2):

You'll have more control over your minions if you use *push*:

- you can control the time when this is run from a central location (you can also disable it in a central location)
- you can batch the updates to avoid running highstate on all hosts at the same time (this will allow five hosts to run the highstate at the same time):

  ```
  salt --batch-size 5 '*' state.highstate
  ```

If you are in a situation that not all hosts are up at the same time, you can ammend this by setting up a [startup state](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/startup.html) that is executed once a minion starts (that can be a specific state, or the highstate).

To check the results you can run

```
salt '*' state.highstate --output=json --static
```

This will give you a JSON output of the executed and failed states. You can then parse the output with a tool of your choice.

A more advanced concept would be to use [Salt Returners](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/), but it is up to you to find out if this is more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the push or pull question
   i. always use the "salt" push command
   ii. Use "salt-call" as last resort for debugging

Actually, when you encounter problem, before debugging , the saltstack best practice is "use a yaml validator to check sls files".